# what problem does "std::size_t huge = static_cast<std::size_t>(-1); ::operator new(huge);" solve in throw_std_bad_alloc?

Tags: c++, eigen

Why is this code written this way， to solve what problem?

"::operator new(huge);" seems to cause a memory leak.

```cpp
EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC 
inline void throw_std_bad_alloc()
{
  #ifdef EIGEN_EXCEPTIONS
    throw std::bad_alloc();
  #else
    std::size_t huge = static_cast<std::size_t>(-1);
    ::operator new(huge);
  #endif
}
```

Comment: do you know what `static_cast<std::size_t>(-1)` is?

Comment: `throw_std_bad_alloc()` sounds self-explanatory to me. Supposedly an invalid `operator new` call terminates the program somehow when exceptions are disabled.

Comment: Is your real question why `throw std:bad_alloc();` shouldn't be sufficient enough, and not having to jump the hoop of creating an unachievable memory allocation request to accomplish that goal?

Comment: @WhozCraig thats my question at least ;). Doesn't `new` throw `bad_alloc` anyhow? So why the two cases?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai - It doesn't just throw, no. The behavior can be customized https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/set_new_handler - and in fact "exception disabled" builds would just terminate.

Answer (score 9):

The function is deviced to throw an exception or do whatever happens when a memory allocation fails.

If `EIGEN_EXCEPTIONS` is defined, it will throw a normal `std::bad_alloc` but in the other case, it'll try to make an allocation of `std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()` bytes (which is what `static_cast<std::size_t>(-1)` results in), which is assumed to always fail so there will be no leak. If exceptions are turned off, it'll most probably `abort()` the program.